# Поиск p-value групп

Tags: математика, r, статистика, rstudio

Есть данные в переменной `SNPs`

```
> str(SNPs)
'data.frame':   1703 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ group: Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ rs1  : Factor w/ 3 levels "D/D","I/D","I/I": 1 1 2 3 3 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ rs2  : Factor w/ 3 levels "a/a","a/b","b/b": 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 3 2 ...
 $ rs3  : Factor w/ 3 levels "G/G","G/T","T/T": 2 1 2 1 1 3 1 1 2 1 ...
 ...other rs


> head(SNPs)
  group rs1 rs2 rs3 ...other rs
1     A D/D b/b G/T
2     A D/D b/b G/G
3     A I/D a/b G/T
4     A I/I b/b G/G
5     A I/I b/b G/G
6     A I/D a/b T/T
```

Я хочу проверить, являются ли различия в двух группах (А и В) между парами rs статистически значимыми. Для этого формирую таблицами с парами

```
> SNPs$rs5_rs6 <- paste(SNPs$rs5, SNPs$rs6)
> tmp <- table(SNPs$rs5_rs6, SNPs$group)
> tmp

              A   B
  4a/4a G/G   1  20
  4b/4a G/G  31  83
  4b/4a G/T  14  51
  4b/4a T/T   1   0
  4b/4b G/G  37 106
  4b/4b G/T  35 119
  4b/4b T/T  11  31
```

И теперь хочу узнать, есть ли статистически значимые различия между группами А и В, например, для второй пары - `4b/4a G/G`. Т.е. сравнить `4b/4a G/G` в группе и в группе B между собой. И так для всех пар (в примере их 7 штук).

Как можно это сделать?

**Более подробное объяснение**

Проведено генетическое исследование образцов ДНК. Исследованы различные полиморфные варианты генов, которые обозначаются `rs1`, `rs2`, `rs3` и т.д. Каждый rs имеет своё обозначение (генотип). Для `rs1` - это  `G/G`,  `G/I` или `I/I`. Для `rs5` - это `4a/4a`, `4b/4a` или `4b/4b`. И так далее. Каждый `rs` имеет какое-то своё обозначение генотипов. Так принято. Все исследованные образцы были разделены на две группы - здоровых и больных (`A` и `В`).

Вклад каждого отдельного rs в развитие какого-либо заболевания незначителен. Но суммарный вклад - с ним стоит считаться. Поэтому стоит задача найти такие пары rs и их генотипов, которые различаются статистически в двух группах. Т.е. такие пары, которые бы говорили о том, что они усиливают риск развития того или иного заболевания.

Таким образом, я беру два `rs` (например) `rs5` (с генотипами a/4a, 4b/4a и 4b/4b) и `rs6` (c генотипами  G/G,  G/I и I/I). И строю таблицу `tmp`, где видно сколько раз встречаются комбинации генотипов (`4a/4a` из `rs5` и `G/G` из `rs6` образуют пару-комбинацию `4a/4a G/G`, которая встречается в группе А 1 раз, в группе B - 20 раз; т.е. только один раз случилось так, что у одного человека одновременно был генотип 4a/4a полиморфизма `rs5` и `G/G` полиморфизма `rs6` в первой группе; во второй группе такое было 20 раз) в `группе A` (здоровых) и в `группе B` (больных).

Теперь я хочу знать, а есть ли статистически значимые различия в частоте встречаемости этих пар между двумя группами, что указало бы на то, что данную пару можно использовать как показатель возможного развития заболевания.

Я решил (может и ошибочно) что нужно посчитать p-value для каждой этой пары с учётом общего количества пар в `группе А` по сравнению с `группой B`.

Возможно нужно использовать тест хи квадрат, составляя для каждой строки моей таблицы `tmp` отдельную таблицу. Например, для первой пары `4a/4a G/G` это будет

```
1     20
129   390
```

129 - это сумма всех пар в `группе A` с вычетом пар первой строки. 390 - это 410-20 для второй группы. И, наверное, нужно делать поправку на количество степеней свободы - тут их будет не 2-1, а 7-1 (семь строк в исходной таблице). Но мне кажется, что я где-то не прав.

Как бы там ни было, я хочу понять, как можно сделать то, что мне нужно - есть ли статистически значимые различия в частоте встречаемости этих пар между двумя группами.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, как вы получили свою таблицу tmp. Ну, например, что такое "G/G" понятно, даже было бы понятно, если бы в ней появились, например "a/b". Но вот что такое "**4**a/**4**b" ?

Непонятны в этой таблице столбцы A и В. Это что, количество появлений указанной пары в каждой из групп? Или что-то другое?

Непонятно, вам надо определить, есть-ли различия между группами А и В  вообще или вам надо определить, есть-ли различие между группой А и В именно для каждой пары в отдельности (т.е. может быть различие по одной паре и отсутствие - по другой)?

Если речь идет о различии между группами по каждой паре в отдельности  по совокупности двух параметров, составляющих единый классифицирующий признак (т.е. на самом деле у вас имеется 9 комбинаций типа "a/a И G/G", "a/b И 
G/T" и т.д, которые можно рассматритвать как единый параметр) то задача сводиться к т.н задаче определения различия между группами по доле в выборке. Наиболее простое пояснение мне встречалось в электронной книгe http://medstatistic.ru/articles/glantz.pdf

Она хоть и для медиков, но написана очень доступно (для студентов младших курсов или продвинутых школьников). Ответ на ваш вопрос на стр.132 и далее. Там же найдете и расчет p-value (точнее - доверительного интервала) для этого случая.

Если вас интересует общее различие между группами А и В на основании всех пар признаков - задача сводится  к критерию сопряженности Пирсона и анализу таблиц сопряженности (есть в любом из учебников). Только вот p-value тут будет возможно определить далеко не всегда.

Если же вы имели ввиду что-то другое - то уточняйте свой вопрос.

Comment: обновил свой вопрос детальной информацией

Comment: По вашему уточнению - классическая задача анализа "доли случаев" -  см. мой ответ, случай 1, ссылка на книгу Гланца. Тем более книга для врачей. Кроме того, если совсем "припечет" советую обратиться на наверняка известный вам специализированный статистический форум для врачей. (Когда-то там я помогал в решении подобной задачу, но там было выявления предрасположенности к заболеваемости от особенности генотипа, связанной с национальностью пациента).

Comment: а можно ли это как-то посчитать в R?

Comment: Давно не использовал R. Но помню, что z-критерий там был. Да и самому его написать - пол часа работы. Кроме того, упомянутый мною форум специализируется именно на R. А если его внимательно почитать, то и "почти свою" задачу там найдете наверняка.

Comment: а можете дать ссылку на этот форум?

Comment: Ну вот, нашел я вам и на R решение. Есть  такая книга Мастицкий С.Э., Шитиков В.К. (2014) Статистический анализ и визуализация данных с помощью R. - электрнонная книга. Там на стр. 167 - ответ на ваш вопрос. С программами на R.

Comment: И форум http://forum.disser.ru/index.php?showforum=46 Надеюсь - теперь справитесь. Будут вопросы - задавайте.